# Are CardTransition modes bugged?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I try to use a CardTransition in kivy. I want to make 'OtherScreen' slide from the right, and when you go back, it will slide back. I tried it with using 'push' and 'pop' as the mode

I tried using only 'push', which works, or only 'pop', which also works, but I can't seem to combine the two

'''

```
MainScreen:
    name: 'main'

    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            text: '2D'
            size: root.height / 2.5, root.height / 2.5
            size_hint: None, None
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.75, 'center_x': 0.5}
            on_press:
                app.root.current = '2d'
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                **root.manager.transition.mode = 'push'**       *# this is push*

            font_size: 50
            background_normal: 'ok.png'


OtherScreen:
    name: '2d'

    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            on_press:
                app.root.current = 'main'
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                **root.manager.transition.mode = 'pop'**     *# and this is pop*

            text: 'back'
```

'''

After I click the first Button, 'OtherScreen' slides in, but after that the animations completely disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Root Cause

The `CardTransition` is not working as you expected because in your app, it switched the screen before setting the direction.

### Snippets

```
        on_press:
            app.root.current = '2d'
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        ...
        on_press:
            app.root.current = 'main'
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

## Solution

1. Set the transition direction
2. Switch screen

### Snippets

```
        on_press:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            app.root.current = '2d'
        ...
        on_press:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            app.root.current = 'main'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I put the direction and the mode before the screen switching, and now it works